# How to create a new DatabaseError instance in Firebase?

Tags: android, error-handling, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to generate a new instance of [DatabaseError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError) object?

Edit:

I'm using a class implementing the ValueEventListener in which I'd like to catch an exception and route the error through `onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)` method.

```
public class StandardSingleValueListener<T> implements ValueEventListener {

    protected Class<T> mTypeClass;

    public StandardSingleValueListener(Class<T> typeClass){
        mTypeClass = typeClass;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        T result = null;
        try {
            result = parseMethod(dataSnapshot);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onCancelled(new DatabaseError(e.toString()); // I'd like to create the error here
            return;
        }
        // process result
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // process databaseError
    }

    protected T parseMethod(DataSnapshot snap){
        return snap.getValue(mTypeClass);
    }
}
```

Where `parseMethod` is sometimes overridden and `mTypeClass` is the class of `T`.

Comment: Your code should never need to *create* a `DatabaseError`. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's probably easier to help if you describe what you're trying to accomplish, giving us some context (and ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) on the use-case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added a use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`DatabaseError` from the exception](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError.html#public-methods) with:

```
DatabaseError.fromException(e);
```

But I'm not sure it's a good idea here. The error you're signaling is an application-level error. Raising it as a `DatabaseError` is bound to lead to confusion to those who maintain the code after you.

Comment: would you therefore suggest in that case to create my own error type, say ParseError? Or wrap DatabaseError within my own error type?

Comment: I just wonder why you catch the exception that may be raised by `parseMethod()` to then just raise another exception for the same error condition. Why not simply let it pass through unmodified?

Comment: I'm handling the database related errors in the code following the onCanceled() callback. Since parseMethod() is used to refine retrieval of data from Firebase (eg, sorting, filtering), it made sense for me to treat it's error similarly to Firebase's DatabaseError. I'm not sure I'm wrapping and then raising another exception like you suggest though. After catching parseMethod() I'm creating an non-throwable Error object so that I could check for it and process it within the onCancelled(). Same way I'd check for and process Firebase's errors passed to onCancelled()